# Como fazer um evento global

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu desenvolvendo um sistema em que, um usuário pode enviar um recado pro outro, (que fica salvo no banco de dados, para se ter um histórico de conversa), porém gostaria de que enquanto o usuário estiver usando outras funções do sistema, ocorresse um evento e abrisse uma janela informando que recebeu uma mensagem.

Pretendo criar uma classe estática que vai ficar verificando se existe novas mensagens. Porém como poderia ativar esse evento, e tratar ele?

**EDIT**

Como vai ter muitos usuários logados no sistema ao mesmo tempo, não existiria algum meio de uma trigger do próprio banco enviar um sinal pro sistema? Pois, temo que prejudique a velocidade do banco se as nesse timer eu ficar abrindo e fechando conexão.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia adicionar um Timer no form que irá exibir as mensagens e no evento Tick pedir para verificar no banco se existe nova mensagem. Você poderia ter na tabela uma columa para informar se a mensagem foi lida ou não, indico um boolean : 0 e 1 no campo e se for true, ele muda o text do form ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Acho que seria legal o `Timer` invocar uma `Thread` que realiza essa verificação, sem bloquear o fluxo principal de execução de atividades do usuário.